# Android Bluetooth Scanner Not Running as a Service

Tags: java, android, service, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I'm trying to run bluetooth beacon scanner as a service, so when the application is not active, when beacon is detected, a notification can.

The Service Code (Java) :

```
public class BtService extends Service {
    public static final String  TAG = BtService.class.getSimpleName();
    private ScanCallback mScanCallback;
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
    private BluetoothLeScanner btScanner;
    private boolean             mIsScanning             = false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate Service");

        final BluetoothManager btManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();

        initBtCallBack();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnStartCommand Service");
        btStartScanning();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        Log.d(TAG, "Destroy");
        btStopScanning();
    }

    /**
     * BlueTooth CallBack
     */
    private void initBtCallBack() {
        Log.d(TAG, "InitBtCallBack");
        try {
            btScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Something found : " + result.getDevice().getAddress());
                BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
                Log.i(TAG, "btDevice : " + device.toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "result : " + result.toString());
                btUseBeacon(result);
            }

        };
    }

    private void btStartScanning() {
        if (btScanner != null) {
            if(! mIsScanning) {
                Log.i(TAG, "START scanning...");

                myBeacons.clear();

                loadMyBeaconList();

                mIsScanning = true;
                btScanner.startScan(mScanCallback);
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "CANNOT START Scanning");
        }
    }

    private void btStopScanning() {
        if(mIsScanning) {
            Log.i(TAG, "STOP scanning");
            mIsScanning = false;
            btScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);

            saveMyBeaconList();
        }
    }
}
```

There also a BroadcastReceiver Class to start the Service

```
public class BtStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, BtService.class);
        context.startService(service);
    }
}
```

Déclaration in the Manifest.xml, between the .  Permission for Boot_Completed as also been added.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<service
    android:name=".BtService"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:enabled="true">
</service>

<receiver android:name=".BtStartServiceReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When the application is active or not, seems it does not work.  In the logcat, I don't see any of the LOG i added in the code of the service.

When I kill the application, the logcat shows that the application is restarting, but nothing about Logs in code.

When I try to run this code adapted for an Activity, It works, beacon are detected and can make notification.

I don't wan't to use any beacon library or SDK, as I work with generic beacon.

Thank's for your help.

Comment: If you kill the application, why would you expect the service to restart?  You only have it set up to start at boot.

Comment: I just discovered that after rebooting the device, it seems working correctly.  I also tried to download the APK (signed) from a server, but I have the same case. How to correct this, to have this working without rebooting the device.
It should work just after the install.  On my Samsung S5, nothing happend, on the Huawey P9, I hear the sound of the notification but not icon in the notification bar.  Both devices, after reboot, it work correctly.

Comment: Understood.  All of these things are a bit tricky to set up.  That's why we build the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) and made it open source, because it handles all these things for you.  I understand you don't want to use a SDK, but realize that as a result, there will be lots of these kinds of complexities that you'll have to solve yourself.  You may want to look at the source code for ideas on solving these problems.  http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/resume-after-terminate.html

Comment: Thank's David, will take a look on this library and take some days to reprogramm the beacon part of the App. But for my case, seems I have to start the service when starting the App for the first time.  But didn't found how to do it ? One the device rebooted, it work correctly.

Comment: RESOLVED ! I found the solution ! Have to start the service after checking the result of request permissions. (BT need ACCES_COARS_LOCATION)